# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject - Create Visualforce Related List with Edit and Delete Action's?

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity

I am trying to create the V**isualforce Related List with Edit and Delete Action's?**

I am getting the below error:

```
04:09:16.0 (12728017)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:4
04:09:16.0 (12737426)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:33
04:09:16.0 (12827556)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:46
04:09:16.0 (12931200)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Class.OpportunityDetailsController.getOppz: line 10, column 1
```

**OpportunityDetailsController**

```
public class OpportunityDetailsController {
    private List<Opportunity> oppz;
    private Contact cntact;

    public OpportunityDetailsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.cntact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Opportunity> getOppz(){
        Contact con = [Select id, Account.id FROM Contact where id =:cntact.id];
        System.debug('Contact & Account Details : '+con.Account);
        if(con.Account == null){
            return null;
        }

        try{
            oppz = [Select id, Name, Account.Name, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity where Account.id =: con.Account.Id];
            System.debug('Opportunity : '+oppz);
            return oppz;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception Coming : '+e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Pagereference editOpp(){
        String oppid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppid'); 
        System.debug('Edit Opp ID : '+oppid);
        return new PageReference('/006/e?id='+oppid+'&retURL=/006/');
    }

    public Pagereference deleteOpp(){
        String oppid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppid'); 
        System.debug('Delete Opp ID : '+oppid);

        Opportunity opp = [Select id from Opportunity where id =:oppid limit 1];
        if(opp != null && opp.Id != null){
            delete opp;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**VFPage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="OpportunityDetailsController">
    <style>
        .fewerMore { display: none;}
    </style>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:messages />
        <apex:detail relatedList="true" />
        <apex:pageBlock id="CustomList" title="Related Opportunities">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppz}" var="o" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(oppz))}" >
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!editOpp}" value="Edit">
                        <apex:param name="oppid" value="{!o.id}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
                </apex:column>

                <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteOpp}" value="Delete">
                    <apex:param name="oppid" value="{!o.id}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>

                <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!o.Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!o.Type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>   
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
     <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" />
</apex:page>
```

After code fixed, I see
[image]

Comment: Can you debug the Contact id? That you are receiving it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class OpportunityDetailsController {
    private List<Opportunity> oppz;
    private Contact cntact;

    public OpportunityDetailsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.cntact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Opportunity> getOppz(){
        List<Contact> con = [Select id, Account.id FROM Contact where id =:cntact.id];

        if(con.size()>0)
        {
            oppz = [Select id, Name, Account.Name, CloseDate, Amount, Type from Opportunity where Account.id =: con[0].Account.Id];
            System.debug('Opportunity : '+oppz);
            return oppz;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }       
    }

    public Pagereference editOpp(){
        String oppid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppid'); 
        System.debug('Edit Opp ID : '+oppid);
        return new PageReference('/006/e?id='+oppid+'&retURL=/006/');
    }

    public Pagereference deleteOpp(){
        String oppid= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppid'); 
        System.debug('Delete Opp ID : '+oppid);

        Opportunity opp = [Select id from Opportunity where id =:oppid limit 1];
        if(opp != null && opp.Id != null){
            delete opp;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Page modification

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="OpportunityDetailsController">
    <style>
        .fewerMore { display: none;}
    </style>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:messages />

        <apex:pageBlock id="CustomList" title="Related Opportunities">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppz}" var="o" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(oppz))}" >
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!editOpp}" value="Edit">
                        <apex:param name="oppid" value="{!o.id}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink> &nbsp; | &nbsp;
                </apex:column>

                <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteOpp}" value="Delete">
                    <apex:param name="oppid" value="{!o.id}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>

                <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!o.Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!o.Type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>   
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: You dont have the opportunity record for the corresponding account ID. Make sure that you have the data

Comment: what is your visual force page URL ?   add ID after that ...  /page/yourPage/ContactID

Comment: When I run the VF code, This is the URL: https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/OpportunityDetailsControllerVFPage?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1

Comment: https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/OpportunityDetailsControllerVFPage?Id=contactID

Comment: replace contactID with your actual contact id

Comment: Please see added screen shot. I was expecting to see only Opportunity RelatedList and not the others. Was my understanding correct ?

Comment: Updated the page..Just see the difference  then you will get an Idea